# Show that it is a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $T : \mathrm{D}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

$\mathrm{D}(\mathbb{R})$ is an infinitely differentiable set of functions with compact support

If $T(\Phi) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Phi(n)$, show $T$ is a distribution.

I know that I should show that they are linear and continuous. But I am not sure about how to show they are continuous.

Answer (score 2):

To show continuity, you need to suppose that you have a sequence $\Phi_j$ in $D(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\Phi_j \to \Phi$ in the topology of $D(\mathbb{R})$ and show that $T(\Phi_j) \to T(\Phi)$.

If $\Phi_j \to \Phi$ in $D(\mathbb{R})$ then there is a compact set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\operatorname{supp} \Phi_j, \operatorname{supp}\Phi \subseteq K$ and $\Phi_j \to \Phi$ uniformly on $K$. Since $K$ is compact, it is bounded and so there exists $N$ such that $K \subseteq [0,N]$. Then
$$T(\Phi_j) = \sum_{n=0}^N \Phi_j(n) \to \sum_{n=0}^N \Phi(n) = T(\Phi)$$
where the convergence follows since the sum is finite and $\Phi_j \to \Phi$ pointwise on $K$.